# repeat function with different arguments if one variable within the function is empty

Tags: bash, function, shell

The function has to check if `TARGET` is empty, and if it is empty i want it to be repeated but this time with `c1TIME=$hours:$minutes:[0-9][0-9]`
then run it, and if it is still empty then with `c1TIME=$hours:$c1minutes[0-9]:[0-9][0-9]`
after that it should stop and echo some info.

`$1` is a standard logfile with errors

`$TIME` string with time in this pattern `HH:MM:SS`
I am sorry if this is confusing, I'm appreciate any help

what this function does in detail:
first it takes a random time for example `12:34:56` and reads only
the "5" in c1seconds, then `c1TIME` is `12:34:5[0-9]`
Target now tries to find a line where the string of c1TIME is located in the logfile and 
prints the number of the line.
`c1DATE` changes the `12:34:5[0-9]` in the found time like `12:34:56` for example.
the rest is actually unimportant

like I said above when `TARGET` is empty it has to run again, so how can i check TARGET while or after the function executed?

```
  function check() {     
    c1seconds=`echo $TIME | awk '{print substr ($1,7,8)}' | head -1c`
    c1TIME=$hours:$minutes:$c1seconds[0-9]
    TARGET=`cat -n $1 | grep "$c1TIME" | awk '{printf "%s\n",$1}' | awk 'sub("$", "")'| head -1`
    c1DATE=`cat $1 | grep "$c1TIME" | grep -Eo "[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}" | head -1`
    EXCEPTION=`tail -$[$WINDOW_LINES-$TARGET] $1 | grep -c Exception`
    ERROR=`tail -$[$WINDOW_LINES-$TARGET] $1 | grep -c Error`
    SEMAPHORE=`tail -$[$WINDOW_LINES-$TARGET]  $1| grep -c semaphore`
    echo $TARGET
    return 0
  }
```

Comment: Are you trying to find the most recent line prior to `$TIME`?

Comment: actually i try to locate the latest line which has a string like a timepattern, because there are no actual timestamps in the logfile, so i look for a line that contains a timepattern, but so i tail or tac the whole file and take the first line which has a timepattern-lokking string in it, if that happens i take the string put it in `$TIME` and use that for my time to calculate the user's input e.g. line 3 of 5 `2013-04-16 23:59:59,942 WARN OutofBounds: dependencies 2;5;1 were dropped] 354112023016210: wrong checksum. got:15 expected:221` so `$TIME="23:59:59"` ; `users Input: 10 minutes`

Comment: `$TIME` is transformed to seconds i subtract both times, `TRUE_TIME=$(($TIME-$USERTIME))` and look for `TRUE_TIME` in the logfile paste every logline between `$TIME` and `$USERTIME` this is not everything, i included many different things to calculate it better, but thats the main idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well you can always use recursion. keep a `level=0` at the global level and call the function again.

```
level=0;
function check() {
```

Now instead of

```
c1TIME=$hours:$minutes:$c1seconds[0-9]
```

use

```
if [ $level -eq 0 ]; then c1TIME=$hours:$minutes:$c1seconds[0-9]; fi
if [ $level -eq 1 ]; then c1TIME=$hours:$minutes:[0-9][0-9]; fi
if [ $level -eq 2 ]; then c1TIME=$hours:$c1minutes[0-9]:[0-9][0-9]; fi
if [ $level -ge 2 ]; then echo "ERROR"; exit; fi
```

Now instead of

```
TARGET=`cat -n $1 | grep "$c1TIME" | awk '{printf "%s\n",$1}' | awk 'sub("$", "")'| head -1`
```

use

```
TARGET=`cat -n $1 | grep "$c1TIME" | awk '{printf "%s\n",$1}' | awk 'sub("$", "")'| head -1`
if [ "x$TARGET" = "x" ]; then ((level++)); check $@; fi
```

I have not run this so typos may be there, but main idea is as the number of recursion and checks are at max 3, use a simple if check with the depth of the recursion. You can modify the series of `if` to `if else`. Also if `grep` can open a file, why `cat file` and pipe it, and if `awk` can search for a pattern in a file, why `cat file | grep pattern` before it?

Comment: for your question, i chose "cat-n" because not every  line has a timestring/timestamp in it, so i just number every line search for the latest string that does look like a timepattern ->> HH:MM:SS
while the user wants all logs lets say 10 minutes ago and then i transform the obtained "10 minutes " minus the latest timestring found, and then i tail the logfile back to find all logs within 10 minutes from now, awk list only the first found timestring of the whole logline
was the best i could think of.
ps. i started bash 4 days ago so i am asure that it could be better just show me the magic ;D

Comment: nonetheless, thats exactly what i needed, thank you very much :D

Comment: well, i didn't fully understand what you said, but `cat -n $1 | grep "$c1TIME" | awk '{printf "%s\n",$1}' | awk 'sub("$", "")'| head -1` this is 1) cat a file with line number,2)grep `$c1TIME` in that;3)print first field,i.e. linenumber,4)remove `$`( should not be needed, previous `awk` is giving only line number),5)print the first match -> `awk -v patt=$c1TIME '$0 ~ patt {print NR; exit}' $1` this should the same thing :) welcome to `awk`

Comment: well it is the same but it takes like 4-8 seconds longer to find the line then my code above with cat-n...but it is way shorter there u are right, well maybe i should say that my logfile has more than 1050000 lines ;D

Answer (score 1):

You want to repeat `while` target is empty: :) so here you go:

```
function check() {

    c1seconds=`echo $TIME | awk '{print substr ($1,7,8)}' | head -1c`
    c1TIME=$hours:$minutes:$c1seconds[0-9]
    TARGET=`cat -n $1 | grep "$c1TIME" | awk '{printf "%s\n",$1}' | awk 'sub("$", "")'| head -1`

    if [ x$TARGET = x ] ; then
           c1TIME=$hours:$minutes:[0-9][0-9] 
           TARGET=`cat -n $1 | grep "$c1TIME" | awk '{printf "%s\n",$1}' | awk 'sub("$", "")'| head -1`
    fi

    c1DATE=`cat $1 | grep "$c1TIME" | grep -Eo "[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}" | head -1`
    EXCEPTION=`tail -$[$WINDOW_LINES-$TARGET] $1 | grep -c Exception`
    ERROR=`tail -$[$WINDOW_LINES-$TARGET] $1 | grep -c Error`
    SEMAPHORE=`tail -$[$WINDOW_LINES-$TARGET]  $1| grep -c semaphore`
    echo $TARGET

}
```

BTW feels like an ugly way to do what you are doing :P

Feels even uglier :) but i don't know what you are trying to accomplish or what your input is so the answer is as it is above.

Comment: actual not what i needed but that's probably my fault...;D
the Problem is when TARGET=`cat -n $1 | grep"$c1TIME" <-- if thats an empty string it should run again with c1Time changed to 
c1TIME=$hours:$minutes:[0-9][0-9]

Comment: aaah errr ...that is just an if statement then :P making the edit now